# What is the first cardinal number which is greater than continuum?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

What is the first cardinal number which is greater than continuum? We denote it by? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\mathfrak{c}^+$ or $( 2^{\aleph_0} )^+$; the $^+$ denotes that we are taking the [*cardinal successor*](http://planetmath.org/CardinalSuccessor.html).  Its value in the (transfinite) sequence of [aleph numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number) cannot be determined by ZFC because the value of $\mathfrak{c} = 2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot be determined by ZFC.

The [Continuum Hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) is the conjecture that $\mathfrak{c} = \aleph_1 = \aleph_0^+$, and was proven to be independent of ZFC by Kurt Gödel (ZFC cannot prove $\mathfrak{c} \neq \aleph_1$) and Paul Cohen (ZFC cannot prove $\mathfrak{c} = \aleph_1$).  Furthermore Paul Cohen's proof showed that given any aleph number $\aleph_\alpha$ ZFC cannot prove $\mathfrak{c} \leq \aleph_\alpha$.

Comment: "Cannot be determined" is a little fuzzy here. We can certainly define a concrete set with this cardinality: it's the set of all order-isomorphism classes of well-orderings of the reals.

Comment: @Henning: I was actually just going to expand on this point.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but it seems to me that by Hartog's construction, there *is* a cardinal $\kappa$ for which ZFC proves $\mathfrak{c} \leq \kappa$ ?

Comment: @us2012: Nope.  If I am thinking about the correct Hartog result, he showed that Hartog showed in ZF(C) that given any set $S$ the set of all ordinals injectible into $S$ is a set, and assuming Choice it follows that if $\kappa$ is the least ordinal (cardinal) not injectible into $S$, then $| S | \leq \kappa$.  This is fine, however there are no _a priori_ bounds on what $\kappa$ should be (in the $\aleph$-sequence) given $S$; in different models of ZFC you might get different $\kappa$'s.  [cont...]

Comment: [..inued] Cohen's method of forcing allows us to start with a model $M$ of ZFC and a $\kappa \in M$ such that $M \models \text{"}\kappa\text{ is an uncountable cardinal"}$ and produce a new model $M^\prime \supseteq M$ in which (1) $M^\prime \models \text{"}\kappa\text{ is a cardinal"}$ for all $\kappa \in M$ such that $M \models \text{"}\kappa\text{ is a cardinal"}$, and (2) $M^\prime \models \text{"}| \mathbb{R} | = \kappa^+ \text{"}$.  This means that ZFC could not prove $| \mathbb{R} | \leq \kappa$.

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the last sentence of your answer somehow. Let me rephrase to see whether I now get it: My point was that ZFC *does* prove $\mathfrak{c} \leq \mathfrak{c}^+$, while your point was that for any ordinal $\alpha$, ZFC *cannot* prove $\mathfrak{c} \leq \aleph_\alpha$ .

Comment: @us2012: Yes.. perhaps I should edit the answer once again.

Comment: Arthur, it's "Hartogs". The "s" is silent (what with being French and all that) :-)

Comment: @Asaf: I lernt to spel fonetikaly.  ;-)

Comment: Dats Nais. :-)${}$

Answer (score 7):

The notation $\beth_1$ represents the cardinality of the continuum. See also, [beth numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number).

Thus, by definition, $(\beth_1)^+$ is the first cardinal number which is strictly greater than $\beth_1$. See also, [successor cardinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successor_cardinal).

Whether $(\beth_1)^+ = \beth_2$ is independent of ZFC. See also, [generalized continuum hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continuum_hypothesis#The_generalized_continuum_hypothesis).

Answer (score 4):

The axioms of ZFC can prove that there exists $\alpha$ such that $\frak c=\aleph_\alpha$, but the axioms themselves are insufficient in order to prove much on that $\alpha$. We can prove that $\alpha\neq 0$ and that $\alpha$ does not have cofinality of $\omega$, whatever that might be.

But besides these two facts we can't say anything intelligible on what exactly is $\alpha$. We know it is possible to have a universe of set theory where $\alpha=1$ and another where $\alpha=2$.

Therefore we cannot really say much on what is $\frak c^+$, or $\aleph_{\alpha+1}$, since we don't know what is $\aleph_\alpha$ in this case. We can, however, prove that it exists and give it a symbol such as:

- $\left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^+$;
- $\frak c^+$;
- $\left(\beth_1\right)^+$

And so on.